# Laravel filament multiselect from the comma separated list

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select, laravel-filament

I am trying to implement [filament admin panel](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin) for a existing project. I would like to implement [multiselect](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#multi-select). Table structure is as below:

#### Products

| id | name | categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product-1 | 1, 2, 4 |
| 2 | product-2 | 1, 2 |
| 3 | product-3 | 2, 4 |
| 4 | product-4 | 4 |

#### Categories

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat-1 |
| 2 | cat-2 |
| 3 | cat-3 |
| 4 | cat-4 |

#### What I tried so far

##### Option 1

I tried to use getter/setter in `product` model like:

```
public function getcategoriesAttribute()
{
    $categoriesId = $this->getRawOriginal('categories');

    return Category::whereIn('id', explode(',', $categoriesId))
        ->get()
        ->pluck('id', 'categories');
}

public function setcategoriesAttribute($ids)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = is_string($ids) ? $ids : implode(',', $ids);
}
```

And in resource file:

```php
...
MultiSelect::make('categories')
...
```

Using this solution I am able to list `categories` correctly but multiselect is not able to either show select nor show list of categories.

##### Option 2

In this solution I tried to use filament `relationship` for fields without getter/setter like below:

```php
MultiSelect::make('categories')
    ->relationship('categories', 'id')
    ->options(fn ($record) => Category::get()->pluck('name', 'id'))
```

This solution is able to list all categories in multiselect dropdown but is not able to show list of already selected categories either in multiselect dropdown nor on index page/table.

#### Solution I am looking for

I would like to list categories as [tags](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/tables/columns#tags-column) in table and also would like to use [multi-select](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#multi-select) while editing the product.

#### Solution

For Laravel 9: Follow answer by Dan Harrin

For Laravel 8: Use traditional way of get/set in the model.

```
public function getCategoriesAttribute($value)
{
    return explode(',', $value);
}

public function setCategoriesAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['categories'] = implode(',', $value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should update the getter and setter so they only explode and implode the comma separated string into an array:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

protected function categories(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => explode(',', $value),
        set: fn ($value) => implode(',', $value),
    );
}
```

Then you should just be able to use the multiselect like normal:

```
MultiSelect::make('categories')
    ->options(Category::pluck('name', 'id'))
```